# How to define modules or classes in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to define a modules/class which have a list of methods. Each of this methods have an instance of some kind of service, like loggers, promises... etc.

How can I do that properly to do a clean code?

In my code I have the next logger definition, but I cannot add more methods because it's not properly to do a large pile of it.

**logger/ticket.js**

```
var log4js = require('log4js');

module.exports = function(){

  var _getTicketLogger = function(){
    var logger = null;

    log4js.loadAppender('file');
    log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file(__dirname + '/../log/ticket.log'), 'ticket-log');

    logger = log4js.getLogger('ticket-log');
    logger.setLevel('DEBUG');

    return logger;
  }

  return { getTicketLogger: _getTicketLogger };
};
```

Comment: Use exports.method_name instead of module.exports

Comment: Is it fine to use? @BibekSubedi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use exports and module.exports so that you can either export your method or function.

`const test = exports = module.exports = {}`

And then add as many methods as you like

```js
test.method1 = function () { ... }

test.method2 = function () { ... }
```